# How can I format-erase my main disk through single user mode?

Tags: imac, restore

I cannot log into my computer anymore and internet recovery is extremely slow, how can i delete the partition and recover to factory stage with single user mode?
Also would erasing it recover my macos to Sierra? I am having troubles with Catalina right now but I am failing to boot my pc.

I did apple diagnostic test but there were no flaws.

Answer (score 1):

You can't realistically recover your OS to factory state from single user mode.  When you boot into single user mode (assuming you enter single user mode with the old style **⌘-S**) you have no GUI and a very minimal set of terminal commands.

If you want to reinstall macOS you need to either boot from an external drive (so the internal disk is offline) or from recovery (which loads a minimal OS into RAM).

If you boot from an external disk could install whatever version of macOS you have - but you would need to download the installer from the app store first.

The version you install from recovery depends on the type of recovery to boot into - see [How to reinstall macOS from macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904)

> > **1. Start up from macOS Recovery**
>
> To start up from macOS Recovery, turn on your Mac and immediately
>   press and hold one of the following combinations on your keyboard.
>   Command-R is generally recommended, especially if your Mac was never
>   upgraded to macOS Sierra 10.12.4 or later.
>
> **Command (⌘)-R** Reinstall the latest macOS that was installed on your Mac (recommended).
>
> **Option-⌘-R** Upgrade to the latest macOS that is compatible with your Mac.
>
> **Shift-Option-⌘-R** Reinstall the macOS that came with your Mac, or the closest version still available.

The simplest would be to restart holding **Option-⌘-R** if you want Catalina

Comment: Recovery is extremely slow and it freezes when i select the main disk in disk utility, the thing that mainly killed my imac is Catalina itself. I guess Ill just buy a new SSD. A quick question, do you know why recovery is slow and I cant progress? Should I try internet recovery instead? Because in normal recovery the spinning circle can stay on for a day.

Comment: oh i tried shift option command r and i think its working, I wasn't sure if my hard drive is dead since the diagnostic test said my hardware is fine, I just have to wait 12-13 hours for my pc to redownload Yosemite and I hope all my problem will go away